# CF7 get placeholder text from php

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

When using CF7 (Contact Form 7) is there any way to get the placeholder text from a php function?
I’ve tried using a shortcode to call the php function, but it doesn’t work.
Here is my test:

function.php code:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'do_shortcode' );
add_shortcode( 'get_placeholder', 'get_placeholder_func' );
function get_placeholder_func () {
    return "Hello world";
}
```

CF7 template:

```
[get_placeholder]
[text the-field placeholder [get_placeholder]]
```

First line works fine and outputs the text returned from the php function.
Second line doesn't work as it only outputs a end-bracket.

I know I can do it by using js/jQuery, but it is a bit messy.
Can anybody help? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the following:

Define the function

```
function get_placeholder_func () {
    return "Hello world";
}
```

Then create your own input for CF7

```
wpcf7_add_form_tag('custom_text_input', 'wpcf7_custom_text_input');
function wpcf7_custom_text_input($tag) {
    if (!is_array($tag)) return '';

    $name = $tag['name'];
    if (empty($name)) return '';
    $placeholder = get_placeholder_func();

    $html = '<input type="text" name="'.$name.'" placeholder="'.$placeholder.'" />';
    return $html;
}
```

Then, when editing CF7 you just have to call the input created

```
[custom_text_input name-of-input]
```

This shortcode will have `name-of-input` name and placeholder declared by the function `get_placeholder_func()`

Hope it works.

Comment: wpcf7_add_shortcode is a deprecated function. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wpcf7_shortcode-is-deprecated-since-contact-form-7-version-4-6/

Comment: Updated with the alternative offered by WPCF7 `wpcf7_add_form_tag()` https://contactform7.com/2016/12/03/contact-form-7-46/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear as to why you would want to do this, but here's a method.

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'cf7_replace_a_string' );
function cf7_replace_a_string( $content ) {
    // Name = Form Tag Name.
    $str_pos = strpos( $content, 'name="the-field"' );
    // If your form field is present.
    if ( false !== $str_pos ) {
        $placeholder = 'this is your placeholder';
        $content     = str_replace( 'placeholder="placeholder"', 'placeholder="' . $placeholder . '"', $content );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Then your form tag would look like this:

```
[text the-field placeholder "placeholder"]
```